# In SQLite3, is it possible to list out specific rows?

Tags: sqlite, count, where-clause, window-functions, sql-limit

Let's say I have a table:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+
| ID        | Score   | email           | add | 
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+
| 123       | 88      | 123@gmail.com   | somewhere | 
| 456       | 77      | 123@gmail.com   |  somewhere   | 
| 789       | 88      | 123@gmail.com   |   somewhere  |     
| 111       | 77      |123@gmail.com    |   somewhere  |    
| 555       | 77      | 123@gmail.com   |   somewhere  |   
|444        | 88      | 123@gmail.com   |    somewhere
| 222       | 77      | 123@gmail.com   |  somewhere |
| 333       | 88     |123@gmail.com     | somewhere    |
```

My question is it possible to select `Score` column and ONLY print out first 3 `88` and `77` Score?

I tried but it seems only give me 3 88 scores only

```
SELECT Score 
FROM Table_Name
WHERE Score = '88' OR Score = '77'
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Which column defines the order of the rows so that *first 3* can be applied?

Comment: I forgot to clarify that, lets say ID column, I'm sorry @forpas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter the table so that only the rows with the scores that you want are returned and then use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to rank the rows of each `Score` based on `ID` so that you can filter out the rows that exceed the first 3 of each group:

```
SELECT ID, Score, email, add
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Score ORDER BY ID) rn
  FROM Table_Name
  WHERE Score = '88' OR Score = '77'
)
WHERE rn <= 3;
```

For versions of SQLite prior to 3.25.0 that do not support window functions use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table_Name t1
WHERE t1.Score = '88' OR t1.Score = '77'
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table_Name t2 WHERE t2.Score = t1.Score AND t2.ID <= t1.ID) <= 3;
```

Comment: I think is my terminal cannot recognize that function ROW_NUMBER(), it says near "(": syntax error

Comment: @HHckC. first check your version of SQLite with `SELECT sqlite_version();`. Window functions were introduced in SQLite in version 3.25.0 (current version is 3.38.0). If you have an older version, then you should consider if possible to upgrade, because although there is an alternative solution for this requirement, the performance will be much lower.

Comment: yea my version is an older version, can you possible briefly tell me the syntax of alternative solution for me pls? I will try it in other way since I have problem that upgrading it

Comment: @HHckC. check my 2nd query.